# android.view.WindowLeaked error cause of alert dialog

Tags: java, android, android-memory

i'm new to android and i have a problem with alert dialog .
there is a method like this :

```
private void deletSelected(){
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setTitle("are you sure?");
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Yes" , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            int deletedRow = getContentResolver().delete(
                    ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI , selectedRow) , null , null);

            if (deletedRow == -1){
                Toast.makeText(EditorActivity.this , "not deleted!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(EditorActivity.this , "deleted successfully" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (dialog != null){
                dialog.dismiss();
            }    
        }
    });
    dialog.setNegativeButton("no" , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (dialog != null){
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    // Create and show the AlertDialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = dialog.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

and a second method like this:

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // User clicked on a menu option in the app bar overflow menu
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to a click on the "Save" menu option
        case R.id.action_save:
            save();
            finish();
            return true;
        // Respond to a click on the "Delete" menu option
        case R.id.action_delete:
            deletSelected();
            finish(); // if i remove this line app will work correctly
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

my problem is that if i remove finish() in onOptionsItemSelected method my app will run correctly but it remain in current activity which i don't want . i want after user press yes in confirmation dialog selected row in dataBase delete and back to main activity but without this line selected row will delete but app doesn't back to mainActivity .

and if i add finish() the confirmation dialog disappear immediately after clicking delete and app will back to main activity without deleting anything .
and in logical the following error shows:

```
08-04 21:57:02.630 28064-28064/com.example.android.pets E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.android.pets.EditorActivity has leaked window android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView{652e345 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-588,144} that was originally added here
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:394)
                                                                         at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:330)
                                                                         at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
                                                                         at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:1279)
                                                                         at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(PopupWindow.java:1118)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatPopupWindow.showAsDropDown(AppCompatPopupWindow.java:105)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.widget.PopupWindowCompatKitKat.showAsDropDown(PopupWindowCompatKitKat.java:33)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.widget.PopupWindowCompat$KitKatPopupWindowImpl.showAsDropDown(PopupWindowCompat.java:129)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.widget.PopupWindowCompat.showAsDropDown(PopupWindowCompat.java:206)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:721)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.tryShow(StandardMenuPopup.java:160)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.show(StandardMenuPopup.java:187)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.showPopup(MenuPopupHelper.java:290)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:175)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter$OpenOverflowRunnable.run(ActionMenuPresenter.java:803)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:743)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5546)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
                                                                         at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:682)
 08-04 21:57:02.631 28064-28064/com.example.android.pets E/WindowManager:      android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.android.pets.EditorAc
```

any idea ?

**EDIT**:
after removing finish() and place it in onClick method . everything is correct now . but i can't understand what is the difference between this two way ?

Comment: add finish() code inside dialog code to avoid this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing the activity that you want to finish into the `deletSelected()` method and call the `activity.finish()` from `onClick()`, instead of calling `finish()` from where you currently have.

Comment: i can't understand what changes are needed to do this . can you explain more clear plz @codaddict

Comment: my problem solved with your solution . thank you very much.
but can you explain briefly what's was the problem . what is the difference between this two approach ?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because after the dialog appears when you click on optionmenuitemselected you are killing the activity without dismissing the AlertDialog. Hence the user is not able to select or press "yes" or "no" as he wish.

all you need to do is put onBackPressed() in the alert dialog's positive button or negative if you want to.

```
private void deletSelected(){
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setTitle("are you sure?");
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Yes" , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            int deletedRow = getContentResolver().delete(
                    ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI , selectedRow) , null , null);

            if (deletedRow == -1){
                Toast.makeText(EditorActivity.this , "not deleted!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(EditorActivity.this , "deleted successfully" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (dialog != null){
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

            **// after performing all you task put this
            onBackPressed();

           // or if you wish to pass some data to previous activity try onActivityResult way.**
        }
    });
    dialog.setNegativeButton("no" , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (dialog != null){
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    // Create and show the AlertDialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = dialog.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: i tried what you said but nothing change and problem is the same as before

Comment: is your deletSelected() and onOptionsMenuItemSelected() are in same activity?

Comment: yes . they are in the same activity . EditorActivity

Comment: so this is happening only when you press R.id.action_delete? Or on this R.id.action_save too?

Comment: try this AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(EditorActivity.this);

and if (deletedRow <= 0) instead of if (deletedRow == -1)

also put a try catch block around the 

int deletedRow = getContentResolver().delete(
                    ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI , selectedRow) , null , null);

line of code and check the exception msg if any.

Answer (score 0):

replace  `new AlertDialog.Builder(this)` with
`new AlertDialog.Builder(EditorActivity.this);` or use getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 0):

On my case, done successfully with this solution:
put  "your_activity.this.finish()" inside handler for idle time with dialog.dismiss().

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          your_activity.this.finish();
      }
},500);
```